# Mass assignment failure in Nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm facing a common problem that novices face with Rails 3.2.3. I am getting error

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_impl, util_location

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :user_impl, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :util_location, :as => :locatable, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible ..., :user_impl_attributes, :util_location_attributes
```

I tried adding accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_impl, :util_location to the code too but that too is not working and giving an altogether different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the basic structure should be as follow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :user_impl_attributes

    has_one :user_impl, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_impl
```